# Get one Entity Collection from Hibernate JOIN Query Result

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, collections

I have 3 table: Messages, MessageTypes, MessageReceivers (MSSQL)

This is my code:
query = session.createQuery("from Messages as  m left join  m.messageReceivers as mr join  m.messageTypes as mt "
                + "where mt.typeName = 'Assignment' "
                + "and mr.accounts.accId =:id");
        query.setParameter("id", recID);
        return query.list();

It return an Object[] (call it O), each element of O is a composition of one Messages- one MEssageReceiver-oneMessagesType

Now i want to get only an List of Messages from that three tables, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add `select m` to your query.

```
query = session.createQuery("select m from Messages as  m left join ...");
```